# StarRocks - error in creating a database and table

Tags: apache-flink, starrocks

We are using below query to add the table in the starrocks: -

```
CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS `DataSync`;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `DataSync`.`Person` (
  `PersonID` INT NOT NULL  COMMENT "",
  `RegistrationNumber` INT NOT NULL  COMMENT ""
) ENGINE=olap
PRIMARY KEY(`PersonID`)
COMMENT ""
DISTRIBUTED BY HASH(`PersonID`) BUCKETS 1
PROPERTIES (
  "replication_num" = "3"
);
```

getting this error - ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 3: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'PRIMARY KEY(`PersonID`)
COMMENT ""
DISTRIBUTED BY HASH(`PersonID`) BUCKETS 1
PRO' at line 5

We changed the table columns and also add and removing the backtick sign but it didn't work.

We are using **flink-connector-starrocks1.2.3_flink-1.14_2.11** and **flink-1.14.5**

Comment: I did not get any errors when I ran this.  I'm running StarRocks 3.1